# Pass vector reference to window process

Tags: c++, winapi

I'm passing a struct that contains a vector reference to a window process using:

```
SetWindowLongPtr(hWnd, 0, (LONG_PTR)&windowExtraData);
```

In the function that creates the window. `windowExtraData` will contain the mentioned reference.

---

Within the window process function I get the passed data with:

```
auto* windowExtraData = (WindowExtraData*)GetWindowLongPtr(hWnd, 0);
```

Should I be worried with memory issues, I mean, when I grow the vector?

Comment: All you're passing is a pointer, as long as what it points to stays valid for the lifetime of the window then there's no problem.

Comment: @JonathanPotter so what you're saying is that I can expect the same behavior as if I was creating a thread with `CreateThread` and passing the struct to that thread, is that correct?

Comment: @anastaciu yes. Whatever you are pointing at, needs to stay alive for as long as that pointer is being used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The vector's growth is internal, and its address doesn't change because of it. Therefore, you can do whatever you'd like with it inside.
Note that if `windowExtraData` is destroyed the pointer won't be valid anymore.